# redux-router pushState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-router

Taken from this project https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example#how-it-works, I have an error at

```
import { pushState } from 'redux-router';
...
checkAuth (isAuthenticated) {
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    let redirectAfterLogin = this.props.location.pathname;
    this.props.dispatch(pushState(null, `/signin?next=${redirectAfterLogin}`));
  }
}
...
```

It says `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reduxRouter.pushState) is not a function`.

I do not run the project as it is, I am implementing the authentication to my own project. Do I missing something?

Comment: try `push` instead of `pushState`

Comment: https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router#pushlocation

Comment: @Utro the error is gone using `push`, but it is not redirected to the given address. The URL on address bar also stays the same as it is.

Comment: Can you show us where and how you wire up your router?

Comment: after some considerations i swap `redux-router` with `react-router-redux` as it works well with other packages and more documentations are available

Answer (score 0):

It is important to add the history to the Router (createHistory). Note: If you have the current history (v 4.3.0) installed, it does NOT have a createHistory function -> use a lower one (v. 3.*.)

Store:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
    import {routerReducer} from 'react-router-redux'
    import { createHistory } from 'history';
    {...more imports}

    const reducer = combineReducers({
        ...rootReducer,
        routing: routerReducer
    });


    function configureStore(initialState) {
        return createStore(
            reducer,
            initialState,
            composeEnhancers(
                applyMiddleware(
                    thunkMiddleware
                ),
                reduxReactRouter({createHistory})
            )
        )
    }

export const store = configureStore(
    {}
);
```

Render Component to DOM

```
import {store} from './store/store';
import {syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
{...more imports}

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            {...}
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Now you can use the pushState-Function

```
import { pushState } from 'redux-router';

export function logoutAndRedirect() {
    return (dispatch, state) => {
        dispatch(logout());
        dispatch(pushState(null, '/login'));
    }
}
```

I hope I have not forgotten anything. -> Add yout history modul to the store